# 3d Print material 2.7x to 2.8 fix

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, 3d-printing

This [shader](https://blendermarket.com/products/3d-print-shader) was a favourite of mine that I can't quite get to work right now, does anyone now to fix it without getting a pink object.[image]